# how to click button using find_element_by_xpath with inner html in selenium webdriver python3.7

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
first_click_content = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='recent-report-wrapper']/div[2]/div/div[6]/div[2]")

print(first_click_content.get_attribute('innerHTML')
```

The above code give the result like this:

```
<button class="buttonWhite js-report-rerun">Re-run</button>
<button class="buttonWhite marginLeft js-report-edit">Edit</button>
<button class="buttonWhite marginLeft js-report-remove">Remove</button>
<button class="buttonWhite marginLeft js-report-save" style="display: none;">Save </button>
<button class="buttonWhite marginLeft js-report-view-errors" style="display: none;">View Errors</button>
<button class="buttonReportGreen marginLeft js-report-view" style="display: none;">View</button>
<button class="buttonReportGreen marginLeft js-report-download" style="display: inline-block;">Download</button>
```

I want to click the first button, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

As the all the buttons are [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) enabled element you need to induce *WebDriverwait* for the desired *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.buttonWhite.js-report-rerun"))).click()
  ```
- `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='buttonWhite js-report-rerun' and contains(.,'Re-run')]"))).click()
  ```
- Note : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```